# Isotretinoin Contraindications

Tags: medications, side-effects, acne, migraine, adverse-events

Why is Isotretinoin (Accutane) contraindicated in migraine patients?

I’ve seen many doctors saying that you should not take isotretinoin if you have a migraine, is there a reason behind it?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Many people hear many things, only some of which are true, so explaining something someone else may have said is sometimes baffling. Please edit your question to add a link to a source (a quote would also be nice) for that stated contraindication. If it's true, there's a reason behind it. Thanks.

Comment: Please cite source(s) for this claim; saying that a lot of doctors say that hardly constitutes evidence. For example, the British Prescribing Information does not mention migraine anywhere: https://www.medicines.org.uk/emc/product/10519/smpc